# I can't transfer data from my hard drive (FAT32) to my laptop

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, backup, fat32

I have been using this hard drive for a while now and recently I haven't been able to transfer files from the hard drive. I have stored close to 500 GB of data and now that I am trying to move some of them onto my laptop the transfer is getting stuck. This is happening for all of the data I am trying to transfer from this hard disk. Is there any way for me to get around this problem?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: After trying to transfer the file the transfer gets stuck at a certain point for a few minutes then it says "The Finder can’t complete the operation because some data in “...” can’t be read or written.
(Error code -36)"